# Is there a way to manually add a subscription to laravel cashier subscription table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier, stripe-payments

How can i create a new subscription for a user on stripe simply by manually inserting rows with the relevant data into the `Laravel/Cashier/Subscription` model.

I already created and retrieved the subscription directly from stripe with this code.

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_mykey');

$stripe_sub = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
  "customer" => "cus_mycus",
  "items" => [
    [
      "plan" => "plan_myplan",
    ],
  ]
]);

$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve(
  $stripe_sub->id
);
```

Now I want to manually update the subscription table by doing something like this

```
use Laravel/Cashier/Subscription as CashierSubscription;

public function addSubscription()
{
   $subscription = new CashierSubscription;
   $subscription->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
   $subscription->stripe_plan = $sub->plan;
   $subscription->quantity = $sub->quantity;
   $subscription->trial_ends_at = $sub->trial_ends;
   $subscription->ends_at = $sub->ended_at;

   $subscription->save();
```

But I get this error response back

```
message: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.
exception: BadMethodCallException
```

Please how can I manually add a subscription to cashier's subscription model.

Comment: `$subscription->save()` shouldn't generate that error... `$subscription` should be an instance of `Laravel/Cashier/Subscription`, which is `class Subscription extends Model`, and `Model` definitely has a `save()` method. Is that the only spot you're calling `->save()` on something?

Comment: must be more code to this as `$sub` is magically defined somewhere outside the scope of that method

Comment: @lagbox 

```
$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve(
  $stripe_sub->id
);
```
The $sub variable is retrieving the subscription by ID

Comment: the point was that isn't all the code, so there might be other stuff left out that you don't think is important, that might be, might even be the actual error potentially :) ... have you determined the error is coming specifically from the `$subscription->save()` call in that method you are showing, by line number of the stack trace?